# Strategies for formatting JSON output from R

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out the best way of producing a JSON file from R. I have the following dataframe `tmp` in `R`.

```
> tmp
  gender age welcoming proud tidy unique
1      1  30         4     4    4      4
2      2  34         4     2    4      4
3      1  34         5     3    4      5
4      2  33         2     3    2      4
5      2  28         4     3    4      4
6      2  26         3     2    4      3
```

```
tmp <- data.frame(
  gender = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  age = c(30, 34, 34, 33, 28, 26),
  welcoming = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L),
  proud = c(4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L),
  tidy = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L),
  unique = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L)
)
```

Using the `rjson` package, I run the line `toJSON(tmp)` which produces the following JSON file:

```
 {"gender":[1,2,1,2,2,2],
 "age":[30,34,34,33,28,26],
 "welcoming":[4,4,5,2,4,3],
 "proud":[4,2,3,3,3,2],
  "tidy":[4,4,4,2,4,4],
  "unique":[4,4,5,4,4,3]}
```

I also experimented with the `RJSONIO` package; the output of `toJSON()` was the same. What I would like to produce is the following structure:

```
  {"traits":["gender","age","welcoming","proud", "tidy", "unique"],
   "values":[   
            {"gender":1,"age":30,"welcoming":4,"proud":4,"tidy":4, "unique":4},
            {"gender":2,"age":34,"welcoming":4,"proud":2,"tidy":4, "unique":4},
            ....
            ]
```

I'm not sure how best to do this. I realize that I can parse it line by line using `python` but I feel like there is probably a better way of doing this. I also realize that my data structure in `R` does not reflect the meta-information desired in my `JSON` file (specifically the `traits` line), but I am mainly interested in producing the data formatted like the line

```
{"gender":1,"age":30,"welcoming":4,"proud":4,"tidy":4, "unique":4}
```

as I can manually add the first line.

---

EDIT: I found a useful [blog](http://theweiluo.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/r-to-json-for-d3-js-and-protovis/trackback/) post where the author dealt with a similar problem and provided a solution. This function produces a formatted JSON file from a data frame.

```
toJSONarray <- function(dtf){
clnms <- colnames(dtf)

name.value <- function(i){
quote <- '';
# if(class(dtf[, i])!='numeric'){
if(class(dtf[, i])!='numeric' && class(dtf[, i])!= 'integer'){ # I modified this line so integers are also not enclosed in quotes
quote <- '"';
}

paste('"', i, '" : ', quote, dtf[,i], quote, sep='')
}

objs <- apply(sapply(clnms, name.value), 1, function(x){paste(x, collapse=', ')})
objs <- paste('{', objs, '}')

# res <- paste('[', paste(objs, collapse=', '), ']')
res <- paste('[', paste(objs, collapse=',\n'), ']') # added newline for formatting output

return(res)
}
```

Comment: Years have gone on since this question was asked.  May I suggest looking at library(jsonlite)  - somebody else provided the answer below.  It doesn't require the apply() transforms and directly produces the expected JSON output.

Comment: @ripvlan - marked jsonlite as answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using the package `jsonlite`:

```
> jsonlite::toJSON(list(traits = names(tmp), values = tmp), pretty = TRUE)
{
  "traits": ["gender", "age", "welcoming", "proud", "tidy", "unique"],
  "values": [
    {
      "gender": 1,
      "age": 30,
      "welcoming": 4,
      "proud": 4,
      "tidy": 4,
      "unique": 4
    },
    {
      "gender": 2,
      "age": 34,
      "welcoming": 4,
      "proud": 2,
      "tidy": 4,
      "unique": 4
    },
    {
      "gender": 1,
      "age": 34,
      "welcoming": 5,
      "proud": 3,
      "tidy": 4,
      "unique": 5
    },
    {
      "gender": 2,
      "age": 33,
      "welcoming": 2,
      "proud": 3,
      "tidy": 2,
      "unique": 4
    },
    {
      "gender": 2,
      "age": 28,
      "welcoming": 4,
      "proud": 3,
      "tidy": 4,
      "unique": 4
    },
    {
      "gender": 2,
      "age": 26,
      "welcoming": 3,
      "proud": 2,
      "tidy": 4,
      "unique": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex - I liked this answer the best.  jsonlite understands data.frame and outputs without the alply()/apply() transform as described in @civilstat answer above.  Also - I ran into an issue with RJSONIO that I haven't been able to resolve that causes all values to be arrays of 1.  jsonlite didn't have this problem.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I am glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 14):

Building upon Andrie's idea with `apply`, you can get exactly what you want by modifying the `tmp` variable before calling `toJSON`.

```
library(RJSONIO)
modified <- list(
  traits = colnames(tmp),
  values = unname(apply(tmp, 1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
)
cat(toJSON(modified))
```

Comment: One problem I have had with both approaches (`rjson` and `RJSONIO`) is that they convert all numbers to strings. For example `2` becomes `"2"`. The code snippet I pasted in as part of my question avoids this problem as it checks for `numeric` and `integer`. Perhaps I should add it as an answer.

Comment: @celenius: My solution applied to your variable `tmp` has integer integers, not converted-to-string integers.  Are you sure you're not doing something silly?

Comment: @RichieCotton hmm. I must have been doing something silly - it was definitely returning integers as strings when I tried it first. No idea why, as when I ran it just now it worked fine (with integers as integers). I hadn't overwritten the `toJSON` function.

Answer (score 9):

Building further on Andrie and Richie's ideas, use `alply` instead of `apply` to avoid converting numbers to characters:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(plyr)
modified <- list(
  traits = colnames(tmp),
  values = unname(alply(tmp, 1, identity))
)
cat(toJSON(modified))
```

plyr's `alply` is similar to `apply` but returns a list automatically; whereas without the more complicated function inside Richie Cotton's answer, `apply` would return a vector or array. And those extra steps, including `t`, mean that if your dataset has any non-numeric columns, the numbers will get converted to strings.
So use of `alply` avoids that concern.

For example, take your `tmp` dataset and add

```
tmp$grade <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
```

Then compare this code (with `alply`) vs the other example (with `apply`).

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me you can do this by sending each row of your `data.frame` to JSON with the appropriate `apply` statement.

For a single row:

```
library(RJSONIO)

> x <- toJSON(tmp[1, ])
> cat(x)
{
 "gender": 1,
"age":     30,
"welcoming": 4,
"proud": 4,
"tidy": 4,
"unique": 4 
}
```

The entire `data.frame`:

```
x <- apply(tmp, 1, toJSON)
cat(x)
{
 "gender": 1,
"age":     30,
"welcoming": 4,
"proud": 4,
"tidy": 4,
"unique": 4 
} {

...

} {
 "gender": 2,
"age":     26,
"welcoming": 3,
"proud": 2,
"tidy": 4,
"unique": 3 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrie, that's a great idea. I'm trying to figure out how to insert a `,` at the end of each line using something like this: `x <- apply(tmp, 1, function(tmp){paste(toJSON, ',')})`. Is there a way to append something to what is returned from `toJSON`?

Comment: Just figured it out: `x <- apply(tmp, 1, function(tmp){paste(toJSON(tmp), ',')})`. Still getting the hang of `apply`!

Comment: @celenius: That looks suspiciously like you are trying to write bits of JSON yourself, which will only end in tears.  Better to manipulate the data into a form where calling `toJSON` gives you what you want.  See my answer.

Comment: @RichieCotton I was just adding a `,` between `{...}{...}`. The output that was produced was not valid JSON. I agree in general though, it's probably not a robust way of doing it.

Comment: The library RJSONIO gave me an issue that I haven't resolved yet.  All values are output as array of 1.   e.g.  { "gender" : [ 2], "age" : [33] }....   However, jsonlite::toJSON() produced the expected output.  { "gender" : 2, "age" : 33 }.   I created by data via ddply(..summarise..) - but I also tried using a simple data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=("a","b","c")) and had the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `split` to split your `data.frame` with N rows into N data.frames with 1 row.

```
library(RJSONIO)
modified <- list(
   traits = colnames(tmp),
   values = split(tmp, seq_len(nrow(tmp)))
)
cat(toJSON(modified))
```