# How to convert data frame to JSON array using R

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

In my current project, I am trying to read data from `csv` file and trying to create hierarchical `JSON` array based on the data from `csv` file in R. Sample data is shown below:

Added data sample data (Reduced the dataset for simplicity):

```
    Country   Provider   2 G Data   3 G Data    LTE     FP0   anfang0   2G  3G  FP1 anfang1
     ABC        A1          n          n         n      fp0      j      NA  NA  NA  NA
     ABC        A2          NA         NA        NA      NA      NA      j   j  fp1 n
     ABC        A3          n          n         n       fp0     j      NA  NA  NA  NA
     DEF        A7          j          j         j       fp0     n       j   j  fp1 n
```

Understanding of data: `n` stands for value is `no`, `j` stands for value is `yes` and `NA` stands for value is missing. `FP0` and `FP1` represent the information about the same provider but in a different area. There are two types of data in a single row i.e.`2 G Data, 3 G Data, LTE, FP0, anfang 0` belong to 1 group and `2G, 3G, FP1, anfang 1` belong to other group. If all information is `n` i.e. `no` then we have to consider corresponding `anfang0` or `anfang1` value.

The sample output is shown below (based on the above explanation):

```
        {
      "ABC": {
        "fp0":[
          {
            "provider": "A1",
            "anfrage": "j"
          },
          {
            "provider": "A3",
            "anfrage": "j"
          }
        ],
        "fp1": [
          {
            "provider": "A2",
            "2G": "j",
            "3G": "j"
          }
        ]
      },
      "DEF": {
        "fp1": [
          {
            "provider": "A7",
            "2G": "j",
            "3G": "j"
          }  
        ],
        "fp0": [
          {
            "provider": "A7",
            "2G": "j",
            "3G": "j",
            "LTE": "j"
          }  
        ]       
      }  
    }
```

In the above `json` format, for each `Country` there should be only single `json` block as shown above. So far I tried to follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524874/trying-to-turn-a-data-frame-into-hierarchical-json-array-using-jsonlite-in-r) but couldn't find any working solution.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
   a=c(a,jsonlite::toJSON(list(list('fp0' = 
   list("provider"=data$Provider[i],"2g"=data$`2 G Data`[i],"3g"=data$`3 G 
   Data`[i],"LTE"=data$LTE[i]))), pretty = TRUE))
}
toJSON(a, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Kindly let me know in case you need more clarity.

Comment: Reproducible data would be nice instead of a picture of a table.

Comment: @snoram- I have added sample data could you please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

#data pre-processing (bind different areas' data in row)
df1 <- df[, 1:7] %>%                          #dataframe having data for one area - i.e. fp0
  na.omit() %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("country", "provider", "2G", "3G", "LTE", "fp", "anfang")) %>%
  bind_rows(
    df[, c(1:2, 8:ncol(df))] %>%              #dataframe having data for another area - i.e. fp1
      na.omit() %>%
      `colnames<-`(c("country", "provider", "2G", "3G", "fp", "anfang"))
    )
df1[df1 == 'n'] <- NA                         #convert all "n" to NA as we are not concerened about it in the final output

#convert processed dataframe to a list
dfList <- lapply(split(df1, df1$country), 
                 function(x) split(x[, c("provider", "2G", "3G", "LTE", "anfang")], x$fp))

#final result (convert list to JSON)
json_out <- toJSON(dfList, auto_unbox = T)
```

which gives

```
> json_out
{"ABC":{"fp0":[{"provider":"A1","anfang":"j"},{"provider":"A3","anfang":"j"}],"fp1":[{"provider":"A2","2G":"j","3G":"j"}]},"DEF":{"fp0":[{"provider":"A7","2G":"j","3G":"j","LTE":"j"}],"fp1":[{"provider":"A7","2G":"j","3G":"j"}]}}
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF"), Provider = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "A7"), `2 G Data` = c("n", NA, "n", "j"), `3 G Data` = c("n", 
NA, "n", "j"), LTE = c("n", NA, "n", "j"), FP0 = c("fp0", NA, 
"fp0", "fp0"), anfang0 = c("j", NA, "j", "n"), `2G` = c(NA, "j", 
NA, "j"), `3G` = c(NA, "j", NA, "j"), FP1 = c(NA, "fp1", NA, 
"fp1"), anfang1 = c(NA, "n", NA, "n")), .Names = c("Country", 
"Provider", "2 G Data", "3 G Data", "LTE", "FP0", "anfang0", 
"2G", "3G", "FP1", "anfang1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

#  Country Provider 2 G Data 3 G Data  LTE  FP0 anfang0   2G   3G  FP1 anfang1
#1     ABC       A1        n        n    n  fp0       j <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#2     ABC       A2     <NA>     <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    j    j  fp1       n
#3     ABC       A3        n        n    n  fp0       j <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>
#4     DEF       A7        j        j    j  fp0       n    j    j  fp1       n
```

Comment: Let me look at this and back to you. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Thanks @Prem  for the perfect answer.